# How to build npm package for Angular 5

Tags: angular5

I try to build a NPM module for Angular 5. I try to repeat structure like another modules, for example: 
https://github.com/juristr/ngx-tabs-libdemo

but it isn't works...
After installing of my package I see error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-chat/index.ts Module build failed: Error:
>   /Users/user/Dropbox/Projects/testngsite/node_modules/ngx-chat/index.ts
>   is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in
>   your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property. The missing file
>   seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published
>   libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an
>   issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to
>   package the library using the Angular Package Format (https://goo.
>   gl/jB3GVv).
>       at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/Users/user/Dropbox/Projects/testngsite/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:674:23)
>       at plugin.done.then (/Users/user/Dropbox/Projects/testngsite/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:467:39)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

How can I solve this problem?
My module: https://github.com/wasteCleaner/ngx-chat

Answer (score 1):

I have been using https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr for some time and works great. Documentation is not amazing but gets the job done. I'm eager to find alternatives but for now I would recommend ng-packagr.